# Minify css - remove angularjs expression in inline style for markup file

Tags: html, css, angularjs, minify

I working with angularjs.

In markup file, I have an inline style like this:

```
<div class="progress-bar"
    style="display: block; width: {{::provision.precision}}%">
</div>
```

I minify this html code by [grunt-contrib-htmlmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin). Here is grunt config:

```
htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: false,
      conservativeCollapse: false,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      removeComments: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeOptionalTags: true,
      minifyJS: {
        mangle: false
      },
      minifyCSS: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.html',
        'views/{,*/}*.html'
      ],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
}
```

There is minifyCSS inside htmlmin to minify inline style using [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin).

The result after minify like that:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="display: block;"></div>
```

There is no width in style attribute.

Does anyone know how to config minifyCSS to keep `width: {{::provision.precision}}%` after minify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Use ng-style instead of style attribute. That's all!